# Sockets Xamarin

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin

I don't know if this is a bug or what, but it sure is strange

I have a Socket that Connects (Obviously) BUT My mobile device doesn't have Airtime, The Socket Still Connects (Strangely) BUT it doesn't send or recieve (Which is fine), How can I disconnect the Socket when airtime is out or detect that the airtime is finnished